# UITextView not editable

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

I am very confused by the following - I realise a difficult question to answer but ...

I have a number of `UITextViews` all set up in exactly the same way. Other than their name and position on the screen they are all identical. All settings are exactly the same in the `File Inspector`. They are established in the same way:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *timeStamps;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *slider1Comments;
```

When a button is pressed they are activated.

```
timeStamps.editable=YES;
[timeStamps setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

slider1Comments.editable=YES;
[slider1Comments setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

However, when I press the button I am not able to enter anything into *timeStamps* while I can in *slider1Comments*.

I have just upgraded to Xcode 5 and noticed a number of changes - maybe it is related. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try doing this

uncheck the "editable" and "user interaction enabled" for both the uitext views and set the delegates for both textviews in interface builder

hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks but this does not do anything

Comment: i have edited my answer check whether it works or not